# In which volume & chapter does Bourbaki define the real numbers?

Tags: reference-request, real-numbers

In which volume of *Elements of Mathematics*, and in which chapter of that volume, does Bourbaki first define the (ordered) field of real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reals are defined in Chapter 4 (Real Numbers) of General Topology, in Section 1. The field of real numbers is then defined in Section 4.